# Static Analysis Tools at Method/Function Level?

Tags: java, function, methods, static-analysis

recently I got into using static analysis tools like sonarqube and Teamscale.

However, they only show metrics at Project/Package/Class level. I am particularly interested in assessing the quality of Java methods, but the only tool I found that returns results at a method level was Sourcemeter and the respective plugin for Sonarqube.

Are there  any other static analysis tools out there that provide metrics at a method level?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you might get a better response at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Metrics/JavaMetrics.html  Check link on that page for sample report.  (My company's product)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com), it gives you many metrics at a method level including Architecture/Design/Implementation metrics.
And by using its code query language you can easily query exactly what you want as metrics, and also calculate your own ones based on the existing metrics.

```
// <Name>Avoid methods too big, too complex</Name>
warnif count > 0 from m in JustMyCode.Methods where 
    (m.NbLinesOfCode > 35 ||
   m.CyclomaticComplexity > 20)

  let complexityScore = m.NbLinesOfCode/2 + m.CyclomaticComplexity 

  orderby complexityScore descending,
          m.CyclomaticComplexity descending
select new { 
   m, 
   m.NbLinesOfCode,
   m.CyclomaticComplexity, 
   complexityScore,

   Debt = complexityScore.Linear(30, 40,    400, 8*60).ToMinutes().ToDebt(),

   // The annual interest varies linearly from interest for severity minor 
   // to interest for severity major
   AnnualInterest = complexityScore .Linear(30,     Severity.Medium.AnnualInterestThreshold().Value.TotalMinutes, 
                                            200, 2*(Severity.High.AnnualInterestThreshold().Value.TotalMinutes)).ToMinutes().ToAnnualInterest()

}
```